# Inhomogeneous biharmonic equation on $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have been tasked with solving $\Delta(\Delta(u)) = f$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $f \in C_c^4(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Frankly, I don't know where to begin. The "naive" thing to do would be to say we can solve $\Delta v=f$ and then $\Delta u =v$, but the solution to $\Delta v=f$ is
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Phi(x-y)f(y) \ dy$$
(where $\Phi$ is the fundamental solution to Laplace's equation) which isn't $C_c^2$, which is all we know how to solve for Poisson's equation for (in Evans; I know that there are more general sufficient conditions).

So then a hands-on approach seems like the only way to go. Indeed, my professor said to find a $\Phi$ whose convolution with $f$ gives the solution. Yet, even in the case of 
$$\Delta(\Delta(u)) = 0$$ 
in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the problem seems unapproachable. I do not know how to solve $u_{xxxx} + 2u_{xxyy} +u_{yyyy} =0$. I have tried looking up results about this equation, but nothing seems helpful at all for the inhomogeneous $\mathbb{R}^d$ case. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, here's the 2D case: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/lpde/lpde504.pdf

Comment: @YuriyS No boundary, just on all of $\mathbb{R}^d$. And general $d$, yes.

Comment: @YuriyS I seem to get the solution, for $d\neq 4$ of $u(x) = \frac{1}{8-2d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(y) |x-y|^2 \Phi(x-y) \ dy$. Of course, I don't know how one would arrive at this solution. And is this even correct?

Comment: Or maybe I wanted $2d-8$, if that matters

Comment: @ DavidBowman, I don't know anything more about this equation, maybe you could see if the answer below helps?

Answer (score 1):

The biharmonic operator is a member of the wider class of polyharmonic operators, defined recursively as
$$
\Delta^m=\Delta(\Delta^{m-1})\quad\forall m\in\mathbb{N}, m\geq 2
$$
where $\Delta=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}+\cdots+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_d^2}$, $d\geq 2$. The inhomogeneous equation involving the polyharmonic operator 
$$
\Delta^m u=f
$$
has been extensively studied for $f$ belonging to different (generalized) function spaces. In particular, being a constant coefficient partial differential operator, by the Hörmander-Malgrange theorem the polyharmonic operator possess a *fundamental solution*, i.e. a solution of the equation 
$$
\Delta^m \mathscr{E}(\mathbf{x})=\delta(\mathbf{x})\quad \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^d
$$
A construction of $\mathscr{E}(\mathbf{x})$ by using the theory of Fourier transform is given by Gel'fand & Shilov in their treatise on distributions [1, §4.2, pp. 201-202]. The result is precisely the following one:
$$
\mathscr{E}(\mathbf{x})=
\begin{cases}
C_{2m}r^{2m-d}\ln r & \text{ if $2m>d$ and $d$ is even,}\\
C_{2m}r^{2m-d} & \text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}
$$
where ([1, §3.3, p. 193, formula (1)])
$$
C_{2m}=2^{2m+d}\pi^{\frac{1}{2}d}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{2m+d}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(-m)},
$$
and $r=\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_d^2}$.

Putting $m=2$ gives you the solution you are searching for, since for every $f\in C^4_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (and also for more general classes of functions)
$$
\Delta^m u(\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{x}) \iff u(\mathbf{x})=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\mathscr{E}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})f(\mathbf{y})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{y}
$$

[1] Gel'fand, I. M.; Shilov, G. E. (1964), *Generalized functions. Vol. I: Properties and operations*, Translated by Eugene Saletan, Boston, MA: Academic Press, pp. xviii+423, ISBN 978-0-12-279501-5, MR 0166596, Zbl 0115.33101.